# Pass PARTIAL VIEW DropdownList Value to PARENT VIEW model in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Partial View referencing a model that is called from a Parent View using  @Html.RenderAction("PartialView", "Controller"). The Partial View is part of a Html.BeginForm. When the parent form renders the dropdown list is displayed. When I fill out the rest of the form fields and click CREATE, the value from the dropdown is not included in the Forms.Collection returned to the controller. How do I pass the PartialView selected value to the Parent View Model?

Here is my Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ArdentTestv6.Repositories.SelectProjectTypes_Result>

<div>
<select id="SelectProjectType" class="alert-danger" title="Please Select">
    <option id="0"></option>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <option id="@item.TypeID"> @item.TypeName </option>

    }

</select>
</div>
```

Here is my Parent View:

```
@model ArdentTestv6.Repositories.ProjectList

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@*Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ProjectList</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div id="projType" class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Project Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @{Html.RenderAction("_ListProjectTypes", "ProjectTypes", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } });}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Project Type ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @{Html.Label("This will hold the ID of the above Project Type", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } });}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectReference, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectReference, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectReference, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectManager, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectManager, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectManager, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateStart, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateStart, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateStart, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCompleted, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCompleted, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCompleted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Where and how are you calling the partial view ?

Comment: Hi, I am calling the Partial View from the Parent View with a RenderAction("_ListProjectTypes etc

Comment: Try giving a unique name to the option as well. Another thing you can try is to receive the value of the dropdown in your controller under a different field and add it back to the model.